# Sort an array/table of words from shortest to longest

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Corona/Lua how to sort a table of strings from shortest to longest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your table is a indexed table and not a keyed one try

```
test = {'123','1234','1245','1','12'}
table.sort(test, function(a,b) return #a<#b end)
for i,v in ipairs(test) do
    print (i,v)
end
```

The important line here is

```
table.sort(test, function(a,b) return #a<#b end)
```

Words will only sorted by length and order within matching lengths will be arbitrary.  If you want to sort by additional criteria, extend the function for the sort 
eg `function(a,b) return #a<#b end`

Comment: Great,  please remember to accept the answer if you are happy with it.